# Set today date as default value in the model

Tags: python, django, date, default

How can I set the default value as today date in a model?

My model:
     vote_date = models.DateField(_('vote date'), null=False, blank=False)

Comment: I would give you a +1 as this is a good think to know but your super fast answer of your own question suggests that you asked before actually looking for a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolve my problem:

```
vote_date = models.DateField(_('vote date'), null=False, blank=False, auto_now=True)
```

[More info about django fields...](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/)

Comment: I think auto_now=True is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers solve the original problem.  Restating the problem, how can I set the default value of a date field to todays date and **still let the user override the default.**

From the DJango docs:

> DateField.auto_now 
>   Automatically set the field to now every time the object
>   is saved. Useful for "last-modified"
>   timestamps. Note that the current date
>   is always used; it's not just a
>   default value that you can override.
>
> DateField.auto_now_add 
>   Automatically
>   set the field to now when the object
>   is first created. Useful for creation
>   of timestamps. Note that the current
>   date is always used; it's not just a
>   default value that you can override.

The answer if this is not just a "when was this added/edited" field, is to use

```
default=datetime.date.today
```

note no parens.  This sets the default to the function, not the value returned by the function when the model is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `auto_now_add` instead, as `auto_now` would change the vote date any time the object is modified.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add

Comment: Oh! Interesting. I imagined votes to be a static thing. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

`django command extensions` can help you with many things like:

> - CreationDateTimeField - DateTimeField that will automatically
>     set it's date when the object is first
>     saved to the database. Works in the
>     same way as the deprecated
>     auto_now_add keyword.
> - ModificationDateTimeField - DateTimeField that will automatically
>     set it's date when an object is saved
>     to the database. Works in the same way
>     as the deprecated auto_now keyword.

http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/