# How to set a variable to be "Today's" date in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, date, datetime, formatting, pandas

I am trying to set a variable to equal today's date.

I looked this up and found a related article:

[Set today date as default value in the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023788/set-today-date-as-default-value-in-the-model)

However, this didn't particularly answer my question.

I used the suggested:

```
dt.date.today
```

But after

```
import datetime as dt     
date = dt.date.today
print date
 <built-in method today of type object at 0x000000001E2658B0>

 Df['Date'] = date
```

I didn't get what I actually wanted which as a clean date format of today's date...in Month/Day/Year.

How can I create a variable of today's day in order for me to input that variable in a DataFrame?

Comment: You just need to call the method. `date = dt.date.today()`

Comment: Be aware that when the next day comes, that date object is still going to represent the previous day.

Answer (score 131):

You mention you are using Pandas (in your title).  If so, there is no need to use an external library, you can just use `to_datetime`

```
>>> pandas.to_datetime('today').normalize()
Timestamp('2015-10-14 00:00:00')
```

This will always return today's date at midnight, irrespective of the actual time, and can be directly used in pandas to do comparisons etc. Pandas always includes 00:00:00 in its datetimes.

Replacing `today` with `now` would give you the date in UTC instead of local time; note that in neither case is the tzinfo (timezone) added.

In pandas versions prior to 0.23.x, `normalize` may not have been necessary to remove the non-midnight timestamp.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('now')` to get time as well.

Comment: neat, but is seems to be the UTC timezone by default

Comment: In pandas 0.23.4, _'today'_ gives current timestamp (not just date)  in local timezone, and _'now'_ gives current timestamp in UTC. So, the behavior to `to_datetime` has changed. Does anybody know if this new behavior is here to stay? [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx)

Comment: Gives a timestamp since v 0.23 : `2019-04-26 15:31:27.103623`

Comment: `curr_date = pd.to_datetime('today').date()` to get just the date

Comment: @NickNick .date() will convert to datetime.date. To keep  the date as a Timestamp, use curr_date = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()

Answer (score 57):

If you want a string `mm/dd/yyyy` instead of the `datetime` object, you can use `strftime` (string format time):

```
>>> dt.datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
                   # ^ note parentheses
'02/12/2014'
```

Answer (score 24):

Using pandas: `pd.Timestamp("today").strftime("%m/%d/%Y")`

Comment: and please use ISO whenever possible `pd.Timestamp('today').strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Answer (score 12):

> pd.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

this will give output as '11/02/2019'

you can use add time if you want

> pd.datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S")

this will give output as '11/02/2019 11:08:26'

[strftime formats](http://strftime.org/)

Answer (score 5):

You can also look into `pandas.Timestamp`, which includes methods like `.now` and `.today`.
Unlike `pandas.to_datetime('now')`, `pandas.Timestamp.now()` won't default to UTC:

```
  import pandas as pd

  pd.Timestamp.now() # will return California time
  # Timestamp('2018-12-19 09:17:07.693648')

  pd.to_datetime('now') # will return UTC time
  # Timestamp('2018-12-19 17:17:08')
```

Answer (score 3):

i got the same problem so tried so many things 
but finally this is the solution.

```
import time 

print (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Answer (score 3):

simply just use `pd.Timestamp.now()`

for example:

input: `pd.Timestamp.now()`

output: `Timestamp('2022-01-12 14:43:05.521896')`

I know all you want is Timestamp('2022-01-12') you don't anything after
thus we could use replace to remove hour, minutes , second and microsecond
here:

input: `pd.Timestamp.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)`

output: `Timestamp('2022-01-12 00:00:00')`

but looks too complicated right, here is a simple way use normalize

input: `pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()`

output: `Timestamp('2022-01-12 00:00:00')`

Comment: use my method you don't needs any thing additional imports

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution in Python3+:

```
import time


todaysdate = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

#with '.' isntead of '/'
todaysdate = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
def today_date():
    '''
    utils:
    get the datetime of today
    '''
    date=datetime.datetime.now().date()
    date=pd.to_datetime(date)
    return date
Df['Date'] = today_date()
```

this could be safely used in pandas dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

There are already quite a few good answers, but to answer the more general question about "any" period:

Use the [function for time periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.to_period.html) in pandas. For Day, use 'D', for month 'M' etc.:

```
>pd.Timestamp.now().to_period('D')
Period('2021-03-26', 'D')

>p = pd.Timestamp.now().to_period('D')
>p.to_timestamp().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2021-03-26'
```

note: If you need to consider UTC, you can use: `pd.Timestamp.utcnow().tz_localize(None).to_period('D')`...

Answer (score 0):

From your solution that you have you can use:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime(date)
```

using the date variable that you use