# Add a column in a dataframe with the date of today like the TODAY function in Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df wit lots of coumnns and I would love to add another column with the name date that contains the date of today like in Excel the TODAY function. How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean something like `df['col'] = pd.Timestamp.now().date()`?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('today')` or if you want no time part `pd.to_datetime('today').normalize()`. This is a `datetime64[ns]` value so it's consistent with other dates

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a variable to be "Today's" date in Python/Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738566/how-to-set-a-variable-to-be-todays-date-in-python-pandas)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is named df, you can use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['new_column']= datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

@Henry Ecker raised the point that the same is possible in native pandas using [pandas.Timestamp.today](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.today.html)

```
df['new_column'] = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: `pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` would do the same without the extra import

Comment: That's a good point, I'll add it. However isn't pandas using datetime anyway? Then I guess the module won't be really imported as it's already in memory?

Comment: `pandas` uses Timestamps (which are roughly equivalent to datetime in terms of behaviour). However internally pandas stores datetimes as type datetime64 (which are not `datetime` objects), but rather the standard numpy type for datetimes and is more performant than using datetime objects (for most things). For this reason, there is a conversion that needs to occur using datetime.today() which does not need to occur when using pd.Timestamp. specifically the conversion to datetime64. That said since this is a string it doesn't really matter all that much in this case.

Comment: @Henry Ecker sorry about your name, that was my phone's autocorrect! And thanks for the info on Timestamps.